# Certain characters in html appear only in chrome but not in other browsers

Tags: html, browser

I am creating a website with greek characters. Here is some of the code:

```
<a href="studenthome.html" class="linking">
ΦΟΙΤΗΤΗΣ
</a>
<a href="secrethome.html" class="linking">
ΓΡΑΜΜΑΤΕΙΑ
</a>
<a href="publisherhome.html" class="linking">
ΕΚΔΟΤΗΣ
</a>
```

While everything works as it should there is a problem with the greek characters in ΦΟΙΤΗΤΗΣ, ΓΡΑΜΜΑΤΕΙΑ etc. When I open it with google chrome I have no problem but when I try with mozilla or ie they appear as ?./????. Why is that and how could I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the charset is not defined correctly. Try adding this in your < head >

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: Well you saved the day. Seems like it works fine now